# How to set a custom font style to a text in Harmony Os i.e setting a new font which is not pre defined in Harmony OS?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I wanted to change the font style of text component(dayTitle) to a custom font for my project. For setting a predefined font ex:- BOLD, Harmony OS platform allows the users to set the predefined fonts in this manner -

```
dateTitle.setFont(Font.DEFAULT_BOLD)
```

Is there any way that I can set custom font to my text component(dayTitle)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your custom font inside **resources/rawfile/** and use the following snippet to access the custom font from resources directory,

```java
    Font createFontBuild(Context context, String name) {
        ResourceManager resManager = context.getResourceManager();
        RawFileEntry rawFileEntry = resManager.getRawFileEntry("resources/rawfile/" + name);
        Resource resource = null;
        try {
            resource = rawFileEntry.openRawFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        StringBuffer fileName = new StringBuffer(name);
        File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), fileName.toString());
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            int index;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            while ((index = resource.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(bytes, 0, index);
                outputStream.flush();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                resource.close();
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        Font.Builder builder = new Font.Builder(file);
        return builder.build();
    }
```